# Forcefully positioning header page numbers for even and odd pages

Tags: formatting, header-footer

I'm trying to write a syllabus and I want the page numbers to be on alternating sides of each page. I am using the package `fancyhdr`, and know the command to accomplish this, `\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}`. But, when I typeset it, the page numbers stay on the right side of the header in all pages. How do I fix this? Please and thank you.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[inner=1.5cm,outer=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.6}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{.7,0,0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,.6,0}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{.98,0,0}
\usepackage[colorlinks,pagebackref,pdfusetitle,urlcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkblue,linkcolor=darkred,bookmarksnumbered,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{ACC 202: Intro to Managerial Accounting}
%\lhead{ \fancyplain{}{Spring 2019 Syllabus} }
%\chead{ \fancyplain{}{} }
%\rhead{ \fancyplain{}{\emph{ACC 202: Intro to Managerial Accounting}} }
%\rfoot{\fancyplain{}{page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
%\fancyfoot[RO, LE] {page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage} }
\thispagestyle{plain}

%%%%%%%%%%%% LISTING %%%
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}
\usepackage{verbatim} % used to display code
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\VerbatimFootnotes % Required, otherwise verbatim does not work in footnotes!
\newcommand{\SubItem}[1]{
    {\setlength\itemindent{15pt} \item[-] #1}
}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}


\definecolor{OliveGreen}{cmyk}{0.64,0,0.95,0.40}
\definecolor{CadetBlue}{cmyk}{0.62,0.57,0.23,0}
\definecolor{lightlightgray}{gray}{0.93}



\lstset{
%language=bash,                          % Code langugage
basicstyle=\ttfamily,                   % Code font, Examples: \footnotesize, \ttfamily
keywordstyle=\color{OliveGreen},        % Keywords font ('*' = uppercase)
commentstyle=\color{gray},              % Comments font
numbers=left,                           % Line nums position
numberstyle=\tiny,                      % Line-numbers fonts
stepnumber=1,                           % Step between two line-numbers
numbersep=5pt,                          % How far are line-numbers from code
backgroundcolor=\color{lightlightgray}, % Choose background color
frame=none,                             % A frame around the code
tabsize=2,                              % Default tab size
captionpos=t,                           % Caption-position = bottom
breaklines=true,                        % Automatic line breaking?
breakatwhitespace=false,                % Automatic breaks only at whitespace?
showspaces=false,                       % Dont make spaces visible
showtabs=false,                         % Dont make tabls visible
columns=flexible,                       % Column format
morekeywords={__global__, __device__},  % CUDA specific keywords
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
stuff
stuff 
stuff
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need the twoside (class) option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, class `article` is onesided. If you want to be printed twosided you need to add class option `twoside`.  Or perhaps you can then use class `report` with option `twoside`, depending on what should happen with the title(page) ...

Please see the following MWE with used package `blindtext` to generate some dummy text with command `\blinddocument`

```
\documentclass[%
  11pt, a4paper,
  twoside % <===========================================================
]{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[inner=1.5cm,outer=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.6}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{.7,0,0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,.6,0}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{.98,0,0}
\usepackage[colorlinks,pagebackref,pdfusetitle,urlcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkblue,linkcolor=darkred,bookmarksnumbered,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{ACC 202: Intro to Managerial Accounting}
%\lhead{ \fancyplain{}{Spring 2019 Syllabus} }
%\chead{ \fancyplain{}{} }
%\rhead{ \fancyplain{}{\emph{ACC 202: Intro to Managerial Accounting}} }
%\rfoot{\fancyplain{}{page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
%\fancyfoot[RO, LE] {page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage} }
\thispagestyle{plain}

%%%%%%%%%%%% LISTING %%%
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}
\usepackage{verbatim} % used to display code
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\VerbatimFootnotes % Required, otherwise verbatim does not work in footnotes!
\newcommand{\SubItem}[1]{
    {\setlength\itemindent{15pt} \item[-] #1}
}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{blindtext} % <==============================================


\definecolor{OliveGreen}{cmyk}{0.64,0,0.95,0.40}
\definecolor{CadetBlue}{cmyk}{0.62,0.57,0.23,0}
\definecolor{lightlightgray}{gray}{0.93}



\lstset{
%language=bash,                          % Code langugage
basicstyle=\ttfamily,                   % Code font, Examples: \footnotesize, \ttfamily
keywordstyle=\color{OliveGreen},        % Keywords font ('*' = uppercase)
commentstyle=\color{gray},              % Comments font
numbers=left,                           % Line nums position
numberstyle=\tiny,                      % Line-numbers fonts
stepnumber=1,                           % Step between two line-numbers
numbersep=5pt,                          % How far are line-numbers from code
backgroundcolor=\color{lightlightgray}, % Choose background color
frame=none,                             % A frame around the code
tabsize=2,                              % Default tab size
captionpos=t,                           % Caption-position = bottom
breaklines=true,                        % Automatic line breaking?
breakatwhitespace=false,                % Automatic breaks only at whitespace?
showspaces=false,                       % Dont make spaces visible
showtabs=false,                         % Dont make tabls visible
columns=flexible,                       % Column format
morekeywords={__global__, __device__},  % CUDA specific keywords
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\blinddocument % <======================================================
\end{document}
```

with resulting pages:

[image]

and

[image]